# Smarty: including a template file from the same directory

Tags: php, smarty

I have a Smarty template located in a directory under `templates_dir`: templates/some/dir/template.tpl . In the same directory, I have a sub-template: templates/some/dir/_component.tpl .

I can't include the sub-component using an unqualified include, since apparently it looks it up under the templates_dir:

```
{include file='_component.tpl'}
```

How can I tell Smarty to read the file from the same directory, as opposed to the templates root ? I do not want to specify absolute paths, since it will cause problems when changing directory structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could your app pass the template dir to the template so it can use it to create an absolute path?

`$smarty->assign('template_d­ir', $smarty->template_d­ir);`

Comment: Hm, yes - it could pass in the directory which I'm using for `$smarty->fetch` . Thanks.